# Is it possible to use external js in a Firefox Extension? e.g. Jquery from CDN

Tags: firefox, cdn, firefox-addon-webextensions

I can't find any reference in the docs to using external js in the [Firefox WebExtensions APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons).

Most [related Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718347/mozilla-firefox-addons-include-external-library-in-main-js) are about the old/legacy Add-on SDK. I'm asking about the new WebExtensions APIs

Is it possible?  For example, can I use the [Jquery](https://code.jquery.com/) or Bootstrap CDN in my extension? If so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mozilla FireFox Addons -> Include external library in main.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718347/mozilla-firefox-addons-include-external-library-in-main-js)

Comment: That questions is for the old API.  Most of SO questions are about the old tech. I've clarified my question.

Answer (score 3):

WebExtension APIs [have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy#Default_content_security_policy) a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) applied to them by default. Its default value is:

```
"script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"
```

I guess the `"script-src 'self'` affects using external js in the WebExtensions. Try this[use the "content_security_policy" manifest key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy) to loosen or tighten the default policy.

And, pay attention to this:

> Note: Valid examples display the correct use of keys in CSP. However, extensions with 'unsafe-eval', 'unsafe-inline', remote script, blob, or remote sources in their CSP are not allowed for extensions listed on addons.mozilla.org due to major security issues.

In https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can load it using background scripts. In the manifest.json file give the following key as

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["jquery.js", "my-background.js"]
}
```

Now you will be able to use jquery in your background script javascript file.

Comment: You can't load external js from a cdn with this.